# Idea for a data migration pipeline in Jenkins and Java

Tags: java, git, docker, jenkins

I am trying to find a solution in order to have some data migration pipeline in my continuous deployment environment. An example of how the data is stored would look like this for the following interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
  String getName();

  List<ISubEntity> getSubEntities();  
}

public interface ISubEntity
{
  String getSomething();

}
```

Payload value in my database for this entity:

```
{"name":"SomeName","subEntities":[{"something":"SomeSomething"}]}
```

So if someone were to remove or rename a method, I would like to update the data in the database as well.

What we have right now in terms of deployment (in short) is something like :

Build project -> Trigger 2nd build to run some tests and put the application inside a docker image -> Recreate k8s pods to run the latest image.

I was thinking I could setup a different repository to handle the data migration and include it in the deployment process the same way we are putting the application in a docker image. Here I would use JGit to find the changes in my entities and create some kind of mapping like:

```
{
  "changedEntity": "IEntity",
  "deletedProperties": [
    "subEntities"
  ],
  "addedProperties": [
    {
      "name": "exoticName",
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": null
    }
  ],
  "changedProperties": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "SomeEnum",
      "defaultValue": "DEFAULT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I was thinking I could retrieve the database entries, use the mapping to create the new data and update it. Wrap this up in a docker image so it can be reused by others consuming the same data and run it on my K8s setup.

My main concern is how to create the mapping itself, would JGit do the trick ? Would there be a better way of applying the mapping on the database as well ? Any input or references would be appreciated.

Thanks